# Custom CRS: different results in PROJ6 and QGIS

Tags: qgis, proj

I have created a custom CRS with PROJ6:

echo 115.90428843055600 -1.92307681111111 126.014 | cct +proj=pipeline +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=deg +xy_out=rad +step +proj=tmerc +lat_0=-1.90355333888889 +lon_0=115.900912891667 +y_0=538.374 +x_0=5200.27 +ellps=GRS80 +step +proj=affine +xoff=-5225.30897756133 +yoff=830.070127940344 +step +proj=affine +s21=-0.0072010369955164367159 +s12=0.0072010369955164367159 +step +proj=affine +xoff=5225.30897756133 +yoff=-830.070127940344 +step +proj=affine +xoff=-9.85881089465147 +yoff=-0.172038726321603 +zoff=-18.541

with the results:
5560.2727     -1623.1404      107.4730           inf

Which is correct.

But when I pass to QGIS (version 3.12.3 with PROJ 6.3.2) the very same proj string I cannot test the values:
[image]

If I erase the first +proj=pipeline we obtain incoherent results:
[image]

How is it possible to obtain the same results in PROJ6 and QGIS (and then used this custom CRS) and why is it not possible, in QGIS, to start a proj string with +roj=pipeline ?

Comment: A proj pipeline is a coordinate operation, not a CRS. They are completely different concepts